# Как правильно склонять: канюль или канюлей?

Tags: орфография, склонение

Как правильно во множественном числе: каню**ль** или каню**лей**?

Answer (score 1):

**Каню́ля** (франц. *canul*e, лат. *cannula*)
Существительное, неодушевлённое, женский род, 1-е склонение (тип склонения 2a по классификации А. А. Зализняка).

1. Короткая трубка с затупленным концом, предназначенная для введения в полости и каналы тела человека или животных с диагностической, лечебной или исследовательской целью.
2. Утолщенная часть трубчатой иглы, предназначенная для ее соединения с различными устройствами.
   (Медицинская энциклопедия)

И.п. канюли
Р.п. **канюль**
[Таким же образом склоняются *бабуля, кастрюля, козюля*.]

*Пользующиеся большим спросом универсальные соединители для **канюль** по типу люэровского запирательного устройства...*
*Медицинский антиклей... для безболезненного удаления пластырей, сенсоров и **канюль.***
*Повязка для фиксации **канюль** из нетканного материала.*

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: "...по классификации А. А. Зализняка"_ === Для справки: в 4-ом издании словаря Зализняка (2007) слова _канюля_ нет, потому я и не сослался на этот словарь в своём ответе. А в каком издании словаря Зализняка это слово есть?

Comment: Я хотела сделать ссылку на орфографический словарь, но Вы его уже в своем ответе обозначили. Слово есть здесь: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8F.

Answer (score 0):

Словарная фиксация: ***канюль***.

См. [[**Букчина Б.З., Сазонова И.К., Чельцова Л.К.  "Орфографический словарь русского языка"**]](http://orthographic.academic.ru/25403):

> **канюля** (1 ж); мн. *канюли, **Р. канюль***

Answer (score 0):

Если верить викисловарю, то ***канюль***.
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8F

Другие словари дают парадигму обычно кратко (канбля, -и). 
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8F

Но это тоже означает, что у слова обычная для этого типа склонения парадигма, включая и форму родительного множественного с нулевым окончанием. В противном случае жто было бы указано явно.

Слово не на слуху, массового автоматизма при формообразовании не выработано , это всё-таки медицина какая-то, но можно сравнить, например, со словом "пилюля": пилюль.

Так что я склонен верить.